# Folium HeatmapWithTime

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I have a dataframe which looks like this :

```
ID                     LAT           LON      VALUE COUNT
81215545953683710540   48.847306     2.433284   0   1
74994612102903447699   48.861935     2.441292   1   1
48126186377367976994   48.839644     2.655109   1   1
23522333658893375671   48.924351     2.386369   4   3
16194691060240380504   48.829872     2.376677   8   1
```

Each `ID` has coordinates, a `VALUE` corresponding to a time interval and a `COUNT` which represents how much people were there.

I want to make a heatmap with time which displays all rows that have the same `VALUE` at a time, taking in account that the bigger the `COUNT` is, the bigger the dot should be.

So far, I succeeded to have a heatmap with time but I struggle with changing the radius of the dots. So every dot have the same size, which I do not want.

What I do understand about the documentation here is that it is normally possible to change the radius : http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-v0.5.0/plugins.html#folium-plugins

My code so far :

```
import folium
import folium.plugins as plugins
%matplotlib inline

heat_df = data

heat_df['Weight'] = heat_df['VALUE']
heat_df['Weight'] = heat_df['VALUE'].astype(float)
heat_df = heat_df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['LAT','LON', 'Weight'])

ma_heatmap = folium.Map(location=[48.512,2.2055],tiles= "OpenStreetMap",
                    zoom_start = 13)

heat_data = [[[row['LAT'],row['LON']] 
                for index, row in heat_df[heat_df['Weight'] == i].iterrows()] 
                 for i in range(0,145)] #value jusqu'à 145

hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(heat_data,auto_play=True,max_opacity=0.8, radius=heat_data['COUNT']*10) #here is my try to change the radius
hm.add_to(ma_heatmap)

ma_heatmap
```

I also made a static heatmap without a count, but here the values are adding themselves so I am satisfied with the dots, but I can't apply the time to it.

It looks like this :

```
import folium 
from folium import plugins
%matplotlib inline

m = folium.Map(location=[48.897634, 2.420086], zoom_start=7)

m.add_children(plugins.HeatMap([[row["LAT"], row["LON"]] for counts, row in data.iterrows()]))

m
```

Either way I can't compute the two methods to get what I want, which is something like this : http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example12.html

If someone has an idea, I will be grateful